# Unknown Column Error On TRIGGER

Tags: mysql, triggers, onupdate

I have created a trigger in my MySQL database, which is meant to set the column named "gps_coordinates" to equal the column named "previous_gps_coordinates" before updating it with the new values.

The problem is on testing, I get the following error message:

> ```
> Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'gps_coordinates' in 'field list'
> ```

My table structure is as follows:

```
|Location Number| gps_coordinates | previous_gps_coordinates
|105285         |Value can be NULL| Value can be NULL
|125896         |Value can be 0   | Value can be 0
```

My Trigger is the following:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER GPSUPDATE
BEFORE UPDATE 
ON sys_reference.location_reference
FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN   
IF NEW.previous_gps_coordinates >= 0 THEN   
SET NEW.previous_gps_coordinates := gps_coordinates;    
END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

I have also tried the variation of:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER GPSUPDATE
BEFORE UPDATE 
ON sys_reference.location_reference
FOR EACH ROW 

BEGIN   
IF NEW.previous_gps_coordinates IS NULL THEN    
SET NEW.previous_gps_coordinates := gps_coordinates;    
END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Any help will be appreciated here. 
Thanks

Comment: Think you need to use OLD... `SET NEW.previous_gps_coordinates := OLD.gps_coordinates;`

Comment: Thanks @RaymondNijland that worked. I saw someone make mention of using `OLD` on a post somewhere, but I didn't use it because unlike the `NEW.` `OLD.` does not get highlighted in blue.

Except now I am getting `Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: '-26.078659 27.758341'` when running an update to a column that has actual co-ordinates.

Comment: Solved this now... Changed the `>= 0` to `IS NOT NULL` and have a second TRIGGER setup for `IS NULL`